# MySql to MySql data migration

Tags: mysql, database, migration

Any solution available for mysql to mysql data migration without  Master/ slave. Any changes in database one  should replicate to database two.

Answer (score 0):

There is now automatic way to do this without replication...

You need to use Master & Slave database.

EDIT: I guess autor of the post is dead lol